# Jquery hover with insertbefore script Not working in IE

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, hover

I am facing issue in jquery hover function with insertbefore script in IE browsers.

Currently i need to swap two div's on hover. So i have used hover with insert before script in drupal7.

Its working fine in all browsers except IE browsers.

Here is my code

```
       $( '.block-views .view-collaborater-view .views-row.views-row-2' )
          .mouseover(function() {
            console.log('mouseover');
            $('.block-views .view-collaborater-view .views-row.views-row-2').insertBefore($('.block-views .view-collaborater-view .views-row.views-row-1'));
            $('.block-views .view-collaborater-view .views-row.views-row-2').css('width','98%');    
          })
          .mouseout(function() {
            console.log('mouseleave');
            $('.block-views .view-collaborater-view .views-row.views-row-2').css('width','48%');
            $('.block-views .view-collaborater-view .views-row.views-row-1').insertBefore($('.block-views .view-collaborater-view .views-row.views-row-2'));
          });
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this, Sorry if mismatch with some class name,

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".block-views .view-collaborater-view .views-row.views-row-2" function(){
    console.log('mouseover');
    $(this).insertBefore($('.block-views .view-collaborater-view .views-row.views-row-1'));
    $(this).css('width','98%');  
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".block-views .view-collaborater-view .views-row.views-row-2" function(){
    console.log('mouseleave');
    $('.block-views .view-collaborater-view .views-row.views-row-1').insertBefore($('.block-views .view-collaborater-view .views-row.views-row-2'));
    $(this).css('width','48%');  
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply.  above code is working fine in chrome and mozilla. I am having same issue in IE. mouse enter event only working. mouse leave function not working in IE. console log shows only mouse enter it wont shows the mouse leave console.

Comment: See the attached screen shot in console log and IE browser

Comment: Try mouseout, instead of mouseleave.

Comment: mouseout also not working @samir. Can you suggest me any other solutions...